# How to change index elements from test.html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hello I need to make a form at test.html that on click changes index elements (title, image, description (text) and a href attribute) with input elements. Can you help me?

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="pal">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button id="ch">Replace the first p element with new text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ch").click(function(){
    $("#pal").replaceWith(#in1);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="in1" type="text"></input>
<input id="in2" type="text"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you help us help you? Where's your code? Can you post a live demo?

Comment: I have only index and I want you guys to tell me how to make the test.html

Comment: Check here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: ok thank you ;) sorry for not being clear

Comment: The problem is `$("#pal").replaceWith(#in1);`. You probably want something like `var content = $("#in1").html(); $("#pal").replaceWith(content);`

Comment: I have 0 experience in jquery and javascript so I think there are a lot of problems

Comment: Ok, just tell me where this new text (the one that replaces the old one on click) is stored and I will give you an answer on how to do that

Comment: the user must write the NEW TEXT at input field and when he clicks the button it should replace the old text, the old text is at INDEX.HTML, the form is at TEST.HTML

Comment: Thid could be done without jQuery. I am not a fan of jQuery :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if i understand well, you have an input tag where the user will write something, and when he clicks on the button, that content will go to another place.

Input where he writes:

```
<input type="text" id="user_text">
```

The place it should go once it is clicked:

```
<p id="pal">This is the target.</p>
```

The click button:

```
<button id="ch">Replace the first p element with new text</button>
```

The JQuery script should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //on click
  $("#ch").click(function(){
    //get content from input (what user wrote)
    var userContent = $("#user_text").val();
    //put it inside the desired div
    $("#pal").html(userContent);
    //clean what user wrote
    $("#user_text").val('');
  });
});
```

If you want to see the result, here is the <kbd>**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vC9M/)**</kbd>

Comment: wow excellent man, but can you make it to replace from TEST.HTML to INDEX.HTML? got me?

Comment: JQuery will only change the page that is currently loaded. You want to  "submit" the form and load index.html with this new content? is that it?

Comment: yes this is what I wanted to say, but I don't speak english very well so I cant express myself, sorry for not being clear what I meant

Comment: Oh. If that is what you want, JQuery is not the best solution. You should do that with PHP. Your form should have as action a PHP file that reads the form and loads index.html (or rather index.php) and sends the text via a POST variable. You'll then build the page using that data. read more: http://goo.gl/zmicX, http://goo.gl/j4zQT

Comment: anyway thanks a lot again and sorry I dont have repution points enough to rate your answer as useful :S I'll read about php and try to make something, thanks again

Comment: if you need any further help, just reply here and i'll be happy to help. good luck! (btw, if you speak French, I can recommend you an excellent PHP tutorial : http://www.siteduzero.com/informatique/tutoriels/concevez-votre-site-web-avec-php-et-mysql)

Comment: thanks but I dont understand french :S I'm Albanian and my second language that I understand is english so thanks a lot for trying to help me